# Use ternary operator while calling function in method

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am making a function for gulpfile, here is the code:

```
var globalSourceMapInit = true;
function makeSaSSTask(taskName, src, isSourceMap, concatFileName, dest){
  gulp.task(taskName, function() {
      return gulp.src(src) //look for all the files in src
          .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init()) //init the sourcemap, sourcemap help in viewing the css as it is in the style tab of inspect element
          .pipe(plugins.sass().on('error', plugins.sass.logError)) //compile sass
          .pipe(plugins.cssmin()) //minify it.
          .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer()) //auto prefix tags like -webkit- -moz- -o- etc wherever required
          .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write()) //write the sourcemap which was inited
          .pipe(plugins.concat(concatFileName)) //concatinate all the files in /src to concatFileName
          .pipe(gulp.dest(dest)); //save concatFileName to dest
  });
}
```

**Now, what I want to do is:** If the isSourceMap and the globalSourceMapInit is true then it should  do sourcemap init otherwise it shall not.

I want it to be something like:

```
return gulp.src(src)
 (isSourceMap && globalSourceMapInit ? .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init()) : null)
 .pipe(...)
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...
 (isSourceMap && globalSourceMapInit ? .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write()) : null)
 .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
```

If this can be the possible solution as to what should I provide rather than `null` in the third operand after : in the ternary operator, or whether it would be valid or not.

I want to know if this is the possible solution and what are the other possible & best ways of achieving this (by using ternary operator).

Comment: Try passing a [noop](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util#noop) (instead of `null`) and always call `pipe`

Comment: thanks @Bergi for letting me know about noop as it already exists in gulp, can you make it as answer?

Comment: I have no idea whether that's official, it's just the second thing I found on Google.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't try to chain everything together. Pipe returns you the changed object. Use it:

```
gulp.task(taskName, function() {
      var p = gulp.src(src); //look for all the files in src

      if (isSourceMap && globalSourceMapInit) {
         p = p.pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init()) //init the sourcemap, sourcemap help in viewing the css as it is in the style tab of inspect element
      }

          p = p.pipe(plugins.sass().on('error', plugins.sass.logError)) //compile sass
          .pipe(plugins.cssmin()) //minify it.
          .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer()) //auto prefix tags like -webkit- -moz- -o- etc wherever required

        if (isSourceMap && globalSourceMapInit) {
           p = p.pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write()) //write the sourcemap which was inited
        }

          return p.pipe(plugins.concat(concatFileName)) //concatinate all the files in /src to concatFileName
          .pipe(gulp.dest(dest)); //save concatFileName to dest
  });
```

Of course you can also store `isSourceMap && globalSourceMapInit` in a variable, to avoid checking twice, but it's a minor.

Comment: I like your solution mate and also good suggestion of storing `isSourceMap && globalSourceMapInit` in a variable, and I could've used it like this too, but as I said I wanted to something like ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

You could use identity transform instead of `null`. Say using `through2` package (haven't tested this)

```
const identity = require('through2')(function(file, _, next){
  this.push(file);
  next()
})

return gulp.src(src)
 .pipe(isSourceMap && globalSourceMapInit ? plugins.sourcemaps.init() : identity)
 .pipe(...)
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...
 .pipe(isSourceMap && globalSourceMapInit ? plugins.sourcemaps.write() : identity)
 .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
```